# Extract out data from the second identifier in regex instead of the first

Tags: regex

I'm trying to obtain the value (john) from name ID and put it under the first capturing group but cant seems to get it. I'm able to get the first one but not the second.

For e.g.

```
Survey Result:13:11:2021:14:15:22 Street Survey Result

Target 1:
    
    name ID: andy
    country name: china
    city name: beijing

Target 2:

    name ID: john
    country name: thailand
    city name: bangkok
```

I'm able to extract out the name andy using the following regex filter: `name ID: \s(.*?)\s`

I saw example of using the same filter `\s(.*?).(.*?)\s` but does not seems to work

or even using the `{1}` to ignore the first non-capturing group but it is getting 'name ID' as group 1, and 'andy' as group 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern you have en extra `\s` at the end, which can match after andy because there is an empty line between the 2 name ID parts.

You can omit the `\s` and you don't have to make the dot non greedy. To match at least a single non whitespace character to not get an empty string, you can start the match with `\S`

To capture the last value in repeating lines with the same format, you can use a capture group in a repeating non capture group:

```
(?:^name ID:\s+(\S.*\s*))+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TEyt4a/1)

If there is more data in between, you can match the last occurrence using a negative lookahead:

```
\bname ID:(?![\s\S]*\bname ID:)\s*(\S+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bname ID:` Match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `[\s\S]*\bname ID:` Optionally match any character and then `name ID:`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(\S+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k0OcRN/1)

Comment: but it is also extracting andy out somehow. i'm trying to see if i can extract out john only.

Comment: @AstralZhang If you have a repeating list of the same formats, you could repeat it like this to get the last capture group `(?:\bname ID:\s+(\S.*\s*))+` See https://regex101.com/r/chJv64/1

Comment: it seems a little bit unusual that when i appended other info within that test data, for e.g.

`name ID: andy
country name: china
city name: beijing

name ID: john
country name: thailand
city name: bangkok`

But it screws up how we are extract john even though we explicitly look for name ID

Comment: @AstralZhang Can you update this link with the data that you are using? https://regex101.com/r/chJv64/1

Comment: In that line, you can capture the last occurrence using `\bname ID:(?!.*\bname ID:)\s*(\S+)`  See https://regex101.com/r/h8H8YW/1

Comment: I'm not able to add the data in the link provided. I have amended the sample set of data above.

Comment: @AstralZhang Did this work out? https://regex101.com/r/h8H8YW/1 Or are there other rules to get the desired result?

Comment: when i tried to paste my sample data above, i get group 1 and group 2 as andy and john respectively, instead of just getting john.

Comment: @AstralZhang Can you paste your example data in https://regex101.com/ and then save the regex at the left top and share the link back here in the comments?

Comment: I have added to the link here - https://regex101.com/r/7XcNAT/1

Comment: @AstralZhang Then is could be like this `\bname ID:(?![\s\S]*\bname ID:)\s*(\S+)` See https://regex101.com/r/k0OcRN/1

Answer (score 0):

Use `name ID:\s(\w+)+` pattern. There will be two matches with specific name in group 1

Here is the link
https://regex101.com/r/AfLb49/1